# How to watch Lync 2013 presentation in full screen?

Tags: lync, lync-2013

How can I watch a Lync presentation in fullscreen? This is using Lync 2013. By default it does 'three quarter screen' which makes text difficult to read.

My colleagues and I use Lync presentations every day and this problem is immensely frustrating to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the top right corner, you have four icons :

- full screen mode
- minimize
- maximize
- close the window

Click on the first icon on the left. It will show the shared screen in full screen mode.

Below those four icons, you have a "Fit to screen" icon if all the presented content doesn't fit in your Lync window.

[Link to the technet site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lync/archive/2012/11/02/presenting-your-screen-in-lync-2013.aspx) :

> **Actual size** shows the content as it appears on presenter’s screen without scaling. This means if presented content is bigger than what can fit in your Lync window, scroll bars will be shown.
>
> **Fit to screen** option on the other hand scales the image such that all the presented content can be seen without the need to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

"In the top right corner, you have four icons :

full screen mode
minimize
maximize
close the window
Click on the first icon on the left. It will show the shared screen in full screen mode.

Below those four icons, you have a "Fit to screen" icon if all the presented content doesn't fit in your Lync window."

This does not display the content being presented in Lync full screen. It displays the content as only a portion of the Lync window, where a user may still even have to use scroll bars to view the content, along with several other brackets (e.g. chat box, participant list) around the content.

The short answer is that Microsoft Lync does not have the capability to view content in full screen.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on this today.  Double click the presentation window and it goes to full screen.  The only problem is you lose your toolbar at the bottom but if willing to live with that this way of viewing is much better.  If a separate lync chat is started you will still get a pop-up in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. Sadly, (stupidly?) you can't.

However you can get close. Right click conversation window and select "full screen". Note how at least 25% of screen real estate is consumed showing a participant gallery. To hide this, click the icon to the top right of the gallery and click "pop out the video gallery". The mugshots dialog can then be minimised and you can reclaim another 20% of the screen. Clicking "Fit to screen" allows you to use the largest area possible, without scrollbars.

Incredibly, lync then replaces the video gallery, the raft of buttons, the scrollbars, the window bar and all that cruft with a thin black band (maybe 2% of screen) that entirely borders the videocast and then a further 1px wide band around the outside of that and a final yellow band on the inside. It's really, really poor but it's as good as you can get with and out-the-box lync install.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Fix!!

Ok after looking everywhere to solve this problem i couldnt find anything, so me and my team from ITT were trying to find out what causes the problem on laptops that we were unable to show the full screen with the plug in app from webpage.
we came up with 2 solutions:

1.- Install skype for bussiness on your computer and use a microsoft account to log in this will fix the problem and you can now start the conference on the skype and not on the web page. this will fix the window not full screen problem.

2 (the one i use) If you dont want to or the company you work for does not allow to use skype on your computers you will have to INSTALL INTERNET EXPLORER 10 or later

No matter if you are using chrome or firefox. this will fix your problem and you will be able to see the full screen and not the 3/4 screen.

I hope this helps to everyone!